# How do I specify a private key for decrypting in gpg

Tags: gnupg, decryption

I use gpg on ubuntu and I have two keyrings I want to decrypt a message with my second private key but gpg uses the first key for decryption.
How I specify private key for decryption?
Thanks!

Comment: What tool are you using ? gpg on the command line ? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292196/gnupg-how-to-encrypt-decrypt-files-using-a-certain-key

Comment: i use gpg built-in from ubuntu
yes from command line

Comment: 1) Are you sure that you have two keyrings? 2) When decrypting, the key is usually selected automatically (and correctly) 3) Or do you mean that you intend to *encrypt*, to create an encrypted file/message?

Comment: See the link I gave you and update your question if that is not a solution.

Comment: when i type gpg --list-secret-keys i have two of them same for my public gpg --list-keys that mean i have two keyrings (two pairs) right? the sender of the message has my public key of second key pair but I dont have his key...so i just want to specify the second private key to decrypt this message

Comment: the link didn't help much :(

Comment: What message is it? `gpg` in its basic way operates with files, encrypts or decrypts a file. Have you created the message to a file in a correct way.

Comment: just a text message and to decrypt it i copied to .txt file so gpg can decrypt it if I provide the correct private key

Comment: How did you create your keys, check that if  `gpg --list-secret-keys` has any output.

Comment: now im not on my linux machine but i used the traditional way for both key pairs gpg --gen-key and then defaults RSA, never expire ,4096 bits.........
I have cheked before both gpg --list-secret-keys and gpg --list-keys and i have both private and public keys

Comment: I need to know if that command has any output to be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry i cant now but as I said before gpg --list-secret-keys prints my 2 keys correctly i just want to select the second one for decryption but gpg uses as default the first

Comment: @George As I know, you don't even need to choose the key. `gpg`  will detect the correct key. asks you the pasphrase and done. do you get any error as output?

Comment: no i dont get any error it just requires the passphrase for first key

Comment: @George Whats happens when you enter the passphrase for that key?

Comment: to be honest i didn't try because when i saw the name of the first key i cancelled the process

Comment: @George  enter your passphrase, I think It's going to work. let me know if that worked for you. we post it as an answer to help others. ;)

Comment: Please try again. Both @Ravexina and I think that the correct key is selected automatically, if it exists in your keyring. Please try and enter the passphrase (password) for the key, that you think was used. If it does not work, try the passphrase for the other key (maybe they were mixed up).

Comment: i tried --try-all-secrets but i have an issue read my comment on the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `--keyring <file>` and `--no-default-keyring`.

From the gpg man page:

```
   --keyring file
          Add  file to the current list of keyrings. If file begins with a tilde and a slash, these are replaced by the $HOME directory. If the filename does not contain a slash, it is assumed to
          be in the GnuPG home directory ("~/.gnupg" if --homedir or $GNUPGHOME is not used).

          Note that this adds a keyring to the current list. If the intent is to use the specified keyring alone, use --keyring along with --no-default-keyring.
```

It does seem odd this would be necessary. Perhaps the encrypted file does not specify the recipient properly or at all?
If it is anonymous you might need to use `--try-all-secrets` also.

Comment: i will try and i will update you!

Comment: i tried it and uses the second key that is very good but when i enter the passphrase nothing happens and it just tries next key i used this command gpg --try-all-secrets --decrypt yyy.asc 
(yyy.asc is the file containing the pgp encrypted messsage)

Comment: ah i tried the next key and worked!!! but still a problem why with the first key... they are mixed up as sudodus said or my mistake? i will try to find out and answer THANK YOU ALL FOR ANSWERS AND TIME!!!

Comment: The encrypted file is normally expected to have the key id of the keypair needed to decrypt it. It's possible the file was created without this info, or with the wrong ID. I don't see a way to tell gpg which key to use, you can only tell it to try them all.

Comment: something really rare happend i imported the public key i gave to see what i really gave and imported my two public keys both thats crazy i just exported the second key....i cant understand what happening here maybe i made a mistake before who knows !

Comment: AAAH now i know i used the gpg --armor --export command only without specifying the name....my mistake sorry for this guys but i found --try-all-secrets very useful thanks a lot to all!!!

Comment: I'm hoping the --try-all-secrets suggestion earns me an accepted answer, if it helped solve your problem. :wink: